# how to read kernel image in arm linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm

I am trying to read kernel image and calculate a checksum value of this image. Firstly, I used a smc instruction to trigger a exception, and in the exception handler, I tried to read the first bytes of the image. I don't really know what the address is, but from some documents, I know the kernel image is decompressed in address like 0x20008000, 0x30008000 or 0xC0008000(they call this ZRELADDR, i don't really know whether this is the right address...). So I tried to read the memory like this:

```
uint32_t test;
test = * (uint32_t *)0x30008000;
DMSG("test : %x\n",test);
```

But the system crashed with a data abort exception,

```
core data-abort at address 0x30008000
 fsr 0x00000005  ttbr0 0x7df7006a  ttbr1 0x7df7006a  cidr 0x0
 cpu #0          cpsr 0x200001b3
 r0 0x00000090      r4 0x7df4bf51    r8 0x00000000   r12 0x00000000
 r1 0x09010000      r5 0x806665e0    r9 0x00000000    sp 0x7df77f50
 r2 0x0000000d      r6 0x7f002000   r10 0x00000000    lr 0x7df273ff
 r3 0x30008000      r7 0x7df77f60   r11 0x00000000    pc 0x7df052f0
ERR TEE-CORE:tee_pager_handle_fault:602: Unexpected page fault! Trap CPU
PANIC: tee_pager_handle_fault core/arch/arm/mm/tee_pager.c:603
```

I guess I am on the wrong way. Does anyone know how to read the kernel image in runtime environment?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**:Thanks for your reply. I am talking about secure kernel. I am trying to check the integrity of the kernel under TrustZone, and to insure the kernel haven't be compromised. So I guess a checksum like hash value may help me. Also, I am a novice who is trying to be familiar with the memory system of arm, so I tried to start with simple read some certain memory address. I have tried to read 0xc0000000 as Artless Noise said, but the same error occurs again. Again I tried to find "_test" and "stext" address in System.map, which is 0x80008000, and error occurs again.

Comment: why do you use smc? are you talking about secure kernel? If you talk about ordinary linux kernel 0xC0008000 should be fine from kernel context

Comment: It might also help to explain _why_ you want this checksum and what you intend to do with it, because superficially it seems pretty worthless: a checksum of a _running_ kernel image is highly unlikely to match that of the same image in storage, or even of the same running image at a different point in time (think static variables, module relocations, etc.)

Comment: Even the kernel space used virtual addresses(the addresses you suggest are physical).  You could try '0xc0000000' or find a variable/define that is going to tell you the actual start/end.  Also, there is probably a map file somewhere for you to look at (even System.map).

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks very much to your all for reply.

Answer (score 0):

The beginning of the RAM is usually mapped at 0xC0000000. This depends on CONFIG_PAGE_OFFSET:

```
 - VMSPLIT_3G: 0xC0000000
 - VMSPLIT_2G: 0x80000000
 - VMSPLIT_1G: 0x40000000
```

Note that this is a virtual address if you have an MMU (usual case), the physical address will depend on your actual architecture (it may or may not be 0x00000000). The kernel is loaded a few pages after that, at an offset of 0x8000.

So, you can probably find the (uncompressed) kernel at 0xC0008000 but it may as well be located somewhere else.

You can also try to ioremap() offset 0x8000 of your RAM.

Can you give us a bit more information on the particular SoC you are working on?

Comment: I am using QEMU to emulate cortex-A15. I have tried 0xC0008000 and the error still happen. When I am in secure mode, I guess the memory address I visited should be physical address. If it should be, then how can I map a virtual address like "0xC0008000" to a physical address?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in secure mode and you believe that in secure mode it access physical address then from below these macro you can deduce the physical address.

The physical address at which kernel loads is PHYS_OFFSET + TEXT_OFFSET (text offset is 0x8000),

PHYS_OFFSET definition will be depend on the CONFIG_ARM_PATCH_PHYS_VIRT  patch.

if CONFIG_ARM_PATCH_PHYS_VIRT is defined, then PHYS_OFFSET will be equal to __pv_phys_offset otherwise PHYS_OFFSET will be defined as CONFIG_PHYS_OFFSET in your kernel config file.

Comment: Thank you for answering. In fact I have got general idea of this exception. It is because the secure OS I am using(OP-TEE) did not map the physical address I want to access to a virtual address. And also I get a bypassing solution - disable the MMU. After I disable the MMU, I can access the physical address directly.